# Cloning a vector of pointers, can I clone an iterator somehow too?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, clone

Have a look at my code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class AbstractBase
{
protected:
    int ident;
public:
    virtual void add() = 0;   
    int getIdent()const {return ident;}
    virtual ~AbstractBase(){};
    virtual AbstractBase* clone()const =0;
};

class Derived1 :public AbstractBase
{    
public:
    Derived1(int i)
    {
        ident=i;
    };
    virtual void add() override
    {
        ident+=1;
    }
    virtual AbstractBase* clone() const override
    {
        return new Derived1 (*this);
    }
};

class Derived2 :public AbstractBase
{    
public:
    Derived2(int i)
    {
        ident=i;
    }
    virtual void add() override
    {
        ident+=2;
    }
    virtual AbstractBase* clone() const override
    {
        return new Derived2(*this);
    }
};

class cloneFunctor
{
public:
    AbstractBase* operator() (AbstractBase* a) const
    {
        return a->clone();
    }
};

struct IdentCompare
{
    bool operator()(AbstractBase* f)
    {
        return f->getIdent() >5;
    }
};

void WorkWithClonedVector(vector<AbstractBase*>origList,vector<AbstractBase*>::iterator it)
{
    vector<AbstractBase*> tempList;
    transform(origList.begin(),origList.end(),back_inserter(tempList),cloneFunctor());
    //NEED TO FIND ITERATOR AGAIN-->ANY OTHER OPTION?
    vector<AbstractBase*>::iterator tempIt=find_if(tempList.begin(),tempList.end(),IdentCompare());
    (*tempIt)->add();
    cout<<"local list:\n";
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<tempList.size();++i)
    {
        cout<<"Element "<<(i+1)<<": "<<tempList[i]->getIdent()<<'\n';
        delete tempList[i];
    }
    cout<<"Original Iterator still pointing to: "<<(*it)->getIdent()<<'\n';
    tempList.clear();
}


int main()
{
    Derived1 d1(1);
    Derived1 d1b(2);
    Derived2 d2(7);
    Derived2 d2b(5);
    vector<AbstractBase*> List;
    List.push_back(&d1);
    List.push_back(&d1b);
    List.push_back(&d2);
    List.push_back(&d2b);
    vector<AbstractBase*>::iterator iter = find_if(List.begin(),List.end(),IdentCompare());
    WorkWithClonedVector(List,iter);
    cout<<"Original List not changed:\n";
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<List.size();++i)
    {
        cout<<"Element "<<(i+1)<<": "<<List[i]->getIdent()<<'\n';
    }
}
```

As you can see I successfully managed to clone a `vector<AbstractBase*>` within `WorkWithClonedVector` in order to safely work on the temporary list without changing anything in the original List. I was wondering if there is any possibility to "clone" the iterator in the parameter list of `WorkWithClonedVector` too, so I don't need to use `find_if` twice? 
To summarize it: if the iterator in the parameter list is pointing to the **third** element of the original list, I'd also like the cloned iterator to point to the **third** element of the cloned list.

Comment: [OT]: Note that you have memory leak in your `WorkWithClonedVector`. Better is than `Clone` method returns `std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase>` (and as you don't use co-variant type, you don't have to add extra methods).

Comment: [OT]: Pass `std::vector` by const reference. and you could add `const`to methods `getIdent()`, `clone()`, `operator()` too.

Comment: thx, I put some of your suggestions in the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you may use instead:

```
auto tempIt = std::next(tempList.begin(), std::distance(origList.begin(), it));
```

or, as you work with `std::vector`

```
auto tempIt = tempList.begin() + (it - origList.begin());
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mhzg3P)

Note that you have to pass `origList` by (const)reference, else `std::distance(origList.begin(), it));` would be UB as the iterator won't belong to the same range.

Comment: thx, but I'm getting a  "cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to *.exe.stackdump" runtime error. I got this to work instead, using pointerss as function parameters:

Comment: `void WorkWithClonedVector(vector<AbstractBase*>* origList,vector<AbstractBase*>::iterator* it)
{
 vector<AbstractBase*> tempList;
    transform(origList->begin(),origList->end(),back_inserter(tempList),cloneFunctor());
    vector<AbstractBase*>::iterator tempIt=tempList.begin()+distance(origList->begin(),*it);
    (*tempIt)->add();
 cout<<"local list:\n";
 for(unsigned int i=0;i<tempList.size();++i)
 {
  delete tempList[i];
 }
 cout<<"Original Iterator still pointing to: "<<(**it)->getIdent()<<'\n';
 tempList.clear();
}`

Comment: @airborne: Some of the fixes of my comment are required to solve the issue. link provided with working version.